# How to allow an NFC intent to fire on certain activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, nfc

In my app, I only have one activity with an NFC intent but it still still fired in all other activities. Is there a way to limit this?

I want to imitate the way [NFC TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo&hl=en) handles their NFC intent. They only allow NFC reads in their "Scan a tag..." activity and it is blocked in all other activites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show some code/manifest, but it doesn't really work like that. The activity selector is handled by the system and fired every time a tag goes into range. If your activity matches it will be in the list. If it is the only app, it will get started automatically. If you use foreground dispatch you can have your activity take priority when it is in the foreground, so that the selection dialog is not shown.

Comment: Yes, activate foreground dispatch in all other activities and simply ignore any NFC-related intents.